# SQL Server 2008 R2 SMO bootstrapper install fails because of dependent product status is unknown

Tags: sql-server-2008, bootstrapper

I am creating a bootstrapper package where it should support all platform [x86,x64,ia64]. When I included all different platform MSI in product.xml of MSXML6.0, SQL CLR type, Native client and SQL 2008 R2 SMO product.xml when I execute setup it fails telling that SMO dependent product MSXML install status is unknown even though it is installed, I checked them in Add/remove programs there it shows that MSXML is installed but when SMO try to install from bootstrapper it fails.

Well if I include only one MSI of any platform in xml of MSXML then SMO installation is success.

Bootstrapper log is

```
Running checks for command 'SMO\sharedmanagementobjects_X86.msi'  
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false  
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'intel': false  
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'smox86' and value '0': false  
Result of running operator 'ValueExists' on property 'smox86reg': false  
Result of checks for command 'SMO\sharedmanagementobjects_X86.msi' is 'Install'  
'SQL server 2008 R2 SMO' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\DOCUME~1\xcxc\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSDDB.tmp\SMO\sharedmanagementobjects_X86.msi
WinVerifyTrust returned 0  
File trusted  
Installing using command 'C:\WINNT\system32\msiexec.exe' and parameters ' -I "C:\DOCUME~1\dfsdf\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSDDB.tmp\SMO\sharedmanagementobjects_X86.msi" -q /qn'  
Process exited with code 1603  
Status of package 'SQL CLR Types' after install is 'InstallUnknown'  
Status of package 'MSXML 6.0' after install is 'InstallUnknown'  
Status of package 'SQL Native Client' after install is 'InstallUnknown'  
Status of package 'SQL server 2008 R2 SMO' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

My SMO-product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product ProductCode="SQL SMO 2008" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="sharedmanagementobjects_X86.msi" HomeSite="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188438&amp;clcid=0x409" PublicKey="3082010A0282010100BD3089FB4572A8536B9E894F0023C0BED41D3DB1594038F373918226E696120053D91C820E3CCE1DBBBDF7428D97D4FC381AE4B9F9E3ECD36103BFA0D3D6754D5C46A9ED5EF0D2E2695B1A73EAB31C8D04CD2944A064592F1E985D6EC7AB18398265C4A7BCAB758819EA87971426B37F2676A4D4383984E3B326D518F92BE9D2C9165A5421F2978D878629FEF4492CE68BF8043F7DCDCD9692860D7103E2D0FE0C4235FFD7B83FDD8E450A7DF6D74BAD5BF076721D77237D8935C41C5DB250034B476D07A75588980680A681AD544ED881D6FABF42C031BE550D99D553491230EBE5A5887C5EC47A5A148708B43769A0EB32248C08EBF9D414BAE0FCCDEAA4150203010001" />
    <PackageFile Name="sharedmanagementobjects_X64.msi" HomeSite="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188439&amp;clcid=0x409" PublicKey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
    <PackageFile Name="sharedmanagementobjects_ia64.msi" HomeSite="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188440&amp;clcid=0x409" PublicKey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
  </PackageFiles>
  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="smox86" Product="{B692E59A-055C-43B7-BE0A-9C2FE0AB88B6}" />
    <RegistryCheck Property="smox86reg" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B692E59A-055C-43B7-BE0A-9C2FE0AB88B6}" />
    <MsiProductCheck Property="smox64" Product="{F10ADDB9-839B-448B-BD2E-3BCB5C1E4B55}" />
    <RegistryCheck Property="smox64reg" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{F10ADDB9-839B-448B-BD2E-3BCB5C1E4B55}" />
    <MsiProductCheck Property="smoia64" Product="{DD33796B-D54B-42CE-BEA8-E4B150FB2EF3}" />
    <RegistryCheck Property="smoia64reg" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{DD33796B-D54B-42CE-BEA8-E4B150FB2EF3}" />
  </InstallChecks>
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="sharedmanagementobjects_X86.msi" Arguments="/qn">
      <InstallConditions>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="smox86" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <BypassIf Property="smox86reg" Compare="ValueExists" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
    <Command PackageFile="sharedmanagementobjects_X64.msi" Arguments="/qn">
      <InstallConditions>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="Anunexpectederroroccurre" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64" />
        <BypassIf Property="smox64" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <BypassIf Property="smox64reg" Compare="ValueExists" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
    <Command PackageFile="sharedmanagementobjects_ia64.msi" Arguments="/qn">
      <InstallConditions>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="Anunexpectederroroccurre" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="ia64" />
        <BypassIf Property="smoia64" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <BypassIf Property="smoia64reg" Compare="ValueExists" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
<RelatedProducts>
        <DependsOnProduct Code="MSXML6.0" />
    <DependsOnProduct Code="SQL CLR TYPES" />
    <DependsOnProduct Code="SQL Native Client" />
 </RelatedProducts>
</Product>
```

MSXML- product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product ProductCode="MSXML6.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="msxml6_x86.msi" HomeSite="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&amp;srcfamilyid=d21c292c-368b-4ce1-9dab-3e9827b70604&amp;srcdisplaylang=en&amp;u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fe%2fa%2ff%2feafb8ee7-667d-4e30-bb39-4694b5b3006f%2fmsxml6_x86.msi" PublicKey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
    <PackageFile Name="msxml6_x64.msi" HomeSite="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&amp;srcfamilyid=d21c292c-368b-4ce1-9dab-3e9827b70604&amp;srcdisplaylang=en&amp;u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fe%2fa%2ff%2feafb8ee7-667d-4e30-bb39-4694b5b3006f%2fmsxml6_x64.msi" PublicKey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
    <PackageFile Name="msxml6_ia64.msi" HomeSite="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&amp;srcfamilyid=d21c292c-368b-4ce1-9dab-3e9827b70604&amp;srcdisplaylang=en&amp;u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fe%2fa%2ff%2feafb8ee7-667d-4e30-bb39-4694b5b3006f%2fmsxml6_ia64.msi" PublicKey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
  </PackageFiles>
  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="msxmlx86" Product="{A43BF6A5-D5F0-4AAA-BF41-65995063EC44}" />
    <MsiProductCheck Property="msxmlx64" Product="{633F3A7E-471D-4C08-A643-C184A2EE19AB}" />
    <MsiProductCheck Property="msxmlia64" Product="{03FCC50D-87AD-44A4-955F-E5D57D089530}" />
  </InstallChecks>
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="msxml6_x86.msi" Arguments="/qn">
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="msxmlx86" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="intel" />
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Success" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
    <Command PackageFile="msxml6_x64.msi" Arguments="/qn">
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="msxmlx64" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
<Command PackageFile="msxml6_ia64.msi" Arguments="/qn">
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="msxmlia64" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="ia64" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

guide me i dont know what i am doing wrong. it is very critical for my project. Thanks in advance.